# Using transform together with nth

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm adding a column with `transform` with the following code:

```
df['new_date'] = df.groupby('account')['date'].transform('last')
```

This works fine, however it by default drops `NaN`s (as documented in existing bugs [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20657), [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427) and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6732)), which I would like to keep. The devs suggest using `nth(-1)` instead. No problem!

However, I can't figure out how to use it with `transform`. The error message for

```
`df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('nth')`
```

is `nth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'`, which seems tantalisingly to suggest that transform recognises the method, as long as I can figure out a way to pass the index to it. But none of

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('nth(-1)')
df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('nth'(-1))
df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('nth')(-1)
```

work. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is possible use second argument for value passed to [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
np.random.seed(2015)

df = pd.DataFrame({'account': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] * 3,
                   'val': np.random.choice([np.nan, 1],size=9)})
#print (df)

df['val1'] = df.groupby('account')['val'].transform('last')
df['val2'] = df.groupby('account')['val'].transform('nth', -1)
print (df)
  account  val  val1  val2
0     foo  NaN   1.0   1.0
1     bar  NaN   1.0   NaN
2     baz  NaN   NaN   NaN
3     foo  NaN   1.0   1.0
4     bar  1.0   1.0   NaN
5     baz  NaN   NaN   NaN
6     foo  1.0   1.0   1.0
7     bar  NaN   1.0   NaN
8     baz  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This example illustrates another point not mentioned in the docs - that `last` will return NaN in the case that _all_ values in the group are NaN.